# How to give “Hidden Sub Menu” inside a “Hidden Sub Menu”

Tags: enterprise-architect

How can i put “Hidden Sub Menu” inside a “Hidden Sub Menu”.

For Example: - I have 4 toolboxes naming A, B, C and D  from which A and B and C are hidden. A is hidden and added to B, B is hidden and added to C, C is hidden and added to D. Now from the Toolbox-D, when I drag and drop “C” I should get B in the list and when I select B, then I should get A in the list and then, when I select A, whatever the elements containing by A should list out as options in the diagram workspace.

How can I achieve this behavior.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? Maybe you'd want to separate the menus instead of giving the user an endless chain of sub-menus, there's only so much space on the screen

Comment: Can you reference an existing MDG where this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a maximum of 2 sub-menus( item in the toolbox->Menu A->Menu B)
An Example I can give is the Events in BPMN(2.0)
Item in toolbox
[image]
Menu A
[image]
Menu B
[image]

The first Sub-Menu is done via the hidden-menu functionality of the Toolbox Profiles.
The second Sub-Menu is done via the [_subtypeProperty Metaclass attribute](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/modeling_tools/supportedattributes_2.html)

The first sub-menu is useful to differentiate stereotypes with similarities of the same Metaclass.

The second sub-menu is useful for assigning a different shape (from conditional branching in the shapescript of the stereotype) to the element on creation. It can also be used to assign the value of a Tagged Value on creation